# Textview within listview with custom adapter is not getting updated

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have got a listview with a custom adapter.

Following is my getView method

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            //inflate the view for each row of listview
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_item, null);
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mViewHolder.mstatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingStatus);
            mViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            view.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

       mViewHolder.mstatus.setText("Status");
        return view;
    }
```

Then Im trying to update the texview `mStatus` in my code as follows,

```
RatingAdapter ratingAdapter = new RatingAdapter(getActivity(), starOneList);
TextView status = (TextView) getViewByPosition(0, mListView).findViewById(R.id.ratingStatus);
 status.setText("New Status");
 mListView.setAdapter(ratingAdapter);
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Log" +
 status.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  ratingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is the the texview is being set but in ui the change is not visible. I mean, the toast message that I get is "New Status" but in ui, the change is not being effected and the textview still displays the old text `Status`. Why is that so?

Comment: After this line mListView.setAdapter(ratingAdapter); why are you notify the adapter?

Comment: should i remove that line?

Comment: Yes try to remove that line. But i am not sure it work because if you scroll the listview then again your mstatus.textview set to "Status" i.e listview refresh (recycle) .

Comment: i tried removing it but it doesnt effect the ui still

Comment: its affect but statically because of mViewHolder.mstatus.setText("Status"); Try to use variable which hold your status value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the text which you want to update on textview each time.
you are now setting textview each time statically i.e. mViewHolder.mstatus.setText("Status");
instead of this your code will be like this mViewHolder.mstatus.setText(newtext); where newtext is some variable which hold new string value

Comment: Yes, Exactly . because it refresh every time when you scroll.

Answer (score 1):

use to following code for refresh your adapter after update to adapter:

```
youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

set the tag in the textview in getview method ,and when you are calling in fragment then get the tag with yourTextview.getTag(),then you set the text to it

Comment: can you please elobrate

Comment: write mViewHolder.mstatus.setTag(position) in getView method after else condition ,then on your fragment class you write mViewHolder.mstatus.getTag==position then mViewHolder.mstatus.setText(New Status).

Answer (score 0):

You have to define like this.

```
 if (convertView == null) {
                //inflate the view for each row of listview
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_item, null);
                mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                mViewHolder.setTag(R.id.ratingStatus, mViewHolder.findViewById(R.id.ratingStatus));
                mViewHolder.setTag(R.id.checkBox, mViewHolder.findViewById(R.id.checkBox));
                view.setTag(mViewHolder);
       } else {
                mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
              }

           mViewHolder.mstatus.setText("Status");
            return view;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    {
        if (convertView == null) {
            //inflate the view for each row of listview
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_item, null);  

            starOneList= HERE_GET_YOUR_LIST_ITEM USING POSITION;  

            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mViewHolder.mstatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingStatus);
            mViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            view.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        mViewHolder.mstatus.setText(starOneList.status); // this is your value that change in activity and only need to notify adapter
        return view;  
}
```

Then

```
// if string array
starOneList[POSITION]="New Status";  
//or   if model class
starOneList.get(POSITION).setStatus("New Status")

    RatingAdapter ratingAdapter = new RatingAdapter(getActivity(), starOneList);

     mListView.setAdapter(ratingAdapter);
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Log" +status.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      ratingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```